# How to call different methods with LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: java, android, localbroadcastmanager

I have 3 menu buttons (`add_image`,`save_meme` and `share_meme`) on my action bar, which are declared in `Mainactivity.java`.  The buttons are responsible for calling the corresponding methods in another fragment.  The connection is established with `LocalBroadcastManager`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Intent saveIntent, shareIntent, addImageIntent;
    LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        addImageIntent = new Intent("ADD_ACTION");
        saveIntent = new Intent("SAVE_ACTION");
        shareIntent = new Intent("SHARE_ACTION");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.add_image:
                localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(addImageIntent);
            case R.id.save_meme:
                localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(saveIntent);
            case R.id.share_meme:
                localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(shareIntent);
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, the corresponding methods are in the `TopImageFragment.java` class.  The `add_image` button calls the method that allows the user to upload an image to the `ImageView` from the device:

```
public void selectedImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
}
```

The `save_meme` button calls the method that saves the bitmap to the device:

```
public void saveMeme(Bitmap btm) {
        counter++;

        File file;
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);

        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath();
        file = new File(path + "/Memery/" + timeStamp + counter + ".jpg");
        file.getParentFile().mkdir();

        try {
            OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            btm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Meme Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

The `share_meme` button calls the method that allows the user to share the meme on a variety of social media apps and email clients:

```
public void shareMeme(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Meme", null);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my Meme");
    getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Your Meme!"));
}
```

But what's happening now is that whenever I select whichever of the 3 menu buttons, all 3 methods get called.  This is my full fragment:

```
public class TopImageFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView topTextView, bottomTextView;
    RelativeLayout topImageRelativeLayout;
    public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    Uri imageUri;
    int counter = 0;
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.CANADA).format(new Date());
    float textSize, x, imageViewArea, canvasArea;
    double val;


    MemeViewModel memeViewModel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_image, container, false);

        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.meme_image_view);

        topTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.top_text_view);
        bottomTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_text_view);

        topImageRelativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.top_image_relative_layout);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            imageUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("imageUri");
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable("imageUri", imageUri);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        memeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).get(MemeViewModel.class);

        memeViewModel.getTopText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable CharSequence charSequence) {
                topTextView.setText(charSequence);
            }
        });

        memeViewModel.getBottomText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable CharSequence charSequence) {
                bottomTextView.setText(charSequence);
            }
        });
    }

    public void selectedImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(ImageView img) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable());
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

        return bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    }

    public Bitmap screenshotMeme() {
        Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(topImageRelativeLayout.getWidth(), topImageRelativeLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        topImageRelativeLayout.draw(new Canvas(image));

        return image.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    }

    public Bitmap drawMeme(Bitmap mutableBitmap) {

        String topText = topTextView.getText().toString();
        String bottomText = bottomTextView.getText().toString();

        topText = topText.toUpperCase();
        bottomText = bottomText.toUpperCase();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);

        TextPaint topFillPaint = new TextPaint();
        TextPaint bottomFillPaint = new TextPaint();

        TextPaint topStrokePaint = new TextPaint();
        TextPaint bottomStrokePaint = new TextPaint();

        Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.impact);

        textSize = topTextView.getTextSize();
        imageViewArea = (imageView.getWidth()) * (imageView.getHeight());
        canvasArea = (canvas.getWidth()) * (canvas.getHeight());
        val = textSize * sqrt(canvasArea / imageViewArea);
        x = (float) val;

        topFillPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        topFillPaint.setTextSize(x);
        topFillPaint.setTypeface(typeface);
        topFillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        topStrokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        topStrokePaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        topStrokePaint.setTextSize(x);
        topStrokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        topStrokePaint.setTypeface(typeface);

        bottomFillPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        bottomFillPaint.setTextSize(x);
        bottomFillPaint.setTypeface(typeface);
        bottomFillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        bottomStrokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        bottomStrokePaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        bottomStrokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        bottomStrokePaint.setTextSize(x);
        bottomStrokePaint.setTypeface(typeface);

        StaticLayout topFillLayout = new StaticLayout(topText, topFillPaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                0.8f, 0.0f, false);
        StaticLayout topStrokeLayout = new StaticLayout(topText, topStrokePaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                0.8f, 0.0f, false);
        StaticLayout bottomFillLayout = new StaticLayout(bottomText, bottomFillPaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                0.8f, 0.0f, false);
        StaticLayout bottomStrokeLayout = new StaticLayout(bottomText, bottomStrokePaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                0.8f, 0.0f, false);

        topFillLayout.draw(canvas);

        topStrokeLayout.draw(canvas);

        canvas.translate(0, canvas.getHeight() - bottomFillLayout.getHeight());
        bottomFillLayout.draw(canvas);

        bottomStrokeLayout.draw(canvas);

        return mutableBitmap;
    }

    public void saveMeme(Bitmap btm) {
        counter++;

        File file;
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);

        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath();
        file = new File(path + "/Memery/" + timeStamp + counter + ".jpg");
        file.getParentFile().mkdir();

        try {
            OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            btm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Meme Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    public void shareMeme(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Meme", null);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/*");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my Meme");
        getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Your Meme!"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            imageUri = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            memeViewModel.setSharedId(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).registerReceiver(addListener, new IntentFilter("ADD_ACTION"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).registerReceiver(saveListener, new IntentFilter("SAVE_ACTION"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).registerReceiver(shareListener, new IntentFilter("SHARE_ACTION"));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver addListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            selectedImage();
        }
    };

    private BroadcastReceiver saveListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            float height = getBitmap(imageView).getHeight();
            float width = getBitmap(imageView).getWidth();

            if ((height <= 600) || (width <= 600)) {
                saveMeme(screenshotMeme());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "screenshotMeme() method was called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                saveMeme(drawMeme(getBitmap(imageView)));
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "drawMeme() method was called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    private BroadcastReceiver shareListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            float height = getBitmap(imageView).getHeight();
            float width = getBitmap(imageView).getWidth();

            if ((height <= 600) || (width <= 600)) {
                shareMeme(screenshotMeme());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "screenshotMeme() method was called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                shareMeme(drawMeme(getBitmap(imageView)));
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "drawMeme() method was called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).unregisterReceiver(addListener);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).unregisterReceiver(saveListener);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).unregisterReceiver(shareListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** Because in switch-case block, you do not return or put a break statement, then whenever a menu item is clicked, it will executes all statements in the switch-case.

**Solution:** Put a `return true` on each case to indicate you want consume the event when a menu item is clicked.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.add_image:
            localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(addImageIntent);
            return true;
        case R.id.save_meme:
            localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(saveIntent);
            return true;
        case R.id.share_meme:
            localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(shareIntent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

or using a `break` statement on each case, then returning true at the end of method.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.add_image:
            localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(addImageIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.save_meme:
            localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(saveIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.share_meme:
            localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(shareIntent);
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: In this case, they might be the same thing.  But generally speaking, what is the difference between `break` and `return true`?

Comment: If you consume the event when a menu item is clicked, then using `return true`. In case you use `break`, then it just exits the switch-case, after that you must return a boolean to indicate whether you consume the click even or not.

Comment: Ah I see.  Thank you very much.  I've upvoted and accepted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos Glad to hear that, happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks.  Also, would you happen to know about sharing a bitmap on the internet without saving it to your device?  I am using this `String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Meme", null);` for a Uri object for the `shareMeme()` method above but it saves the bitmap in my device when I only want to share it.

Comment: I think your code is fine, in case you want to save storage after sharing the bitmap on the internet, then try to delete the image from the storage after sharing.

Comment: How can I delete the image from storage programmatically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191147/discussion-between-andros-adrianopolos-and-tommy).